# How to swap text input values on clicking button using angular 2 or angular 4?

Tags: angular, swap

I have two text boxes name1 and name2, after filling those if I click swap it button the text box values should swap.

[image: 1]

After clicking swap it button

[image: 2]

Comment: can you add your code

Comment: <input type="text" #nameone [value]="nametwo.value"/>
  <input type="text" #nametwo  [value]="nameone.value"/>
  <button (click)="getValue(nameone.value, nametwo.value)">Get Value</button>
 `
})
export class CoursesComponent 
{
  getValue(nameone, nametwo){
    console.log(nameone nametwo);
    return nametwo, nameone;
  }
}

Comment: In JavaScript its just four lines code:                                                             
    var x = document.getElementById("one").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("two").value;
    document.getElementById("two").value = x;
    document.getElementById("one").value = y;

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/swap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ngModel directive binds an input

**component.html**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="demo" >
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="demo1" >
<button (click)="onSwap(demo,demo1)">Swap</button>
```

**component.ts**

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';   
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
    })
    export class AppComponent  {
      name = 'Angular';
      demo;
      demo1;
      onSwap(demo,demo1){
        this.demo1=demo;
        this.demo=demo1;
      }
    }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/swap

Comment: Just a comment, this is not a template driven form ;)

Comment: Thank you very much Chellappan. Its working fine here. I newly started angular bit confused with initialization.

Comment: @AJT_82 sorry i have changed

Answer (score 0):

you can use reference variable to achieve it, In HTML file

```
<input type='text' #v>
<input type="text" #v1>
<button (click)='x=v.value; v.value = v1.value; v1.value = x'>Swap</button>
```